# Create Multiple Text File, With The Name Of Every File Based In A Cell

Tags: excel, vba, text-files

I'm pretty new in VBA and in code in general.

My questions is the next:

In my work I have to create different text files to send the information to a server, so I must create several files,
So I have a Excel with these:

In column "A" will be the names that I want to create for each text file.

In column "B" will be the body of the text file

But in the first cell of column "B" I have to change the cell value of each of the values ​​in column "A"

So, Could anybody help me to know how to do it?

```
Sub CreateFiles_2()


    Dim sExportFolder, sFN
    Dim rName As Range
    Dim action As Range
    Dim oSH As Worksheet
    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim oTxt As Object

    'sExportFolder = path to the folder you want to export to
    'oSh = The sheet where your data is stored

    sExportFolder = "C:\Users\DATEFILES\"
    Set oSH = Worksheets("INDEX")

    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

    For Each rName In oSH.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
        Set action = rName.Offset(, 1)


        'Add .txt to the article name as a file name

        sFN = rName.Value & ".txt"
        Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & "\" & sFN, 2, True)
        oTxt.WriteLine action.Value
        oTxt.Close
    Next


End Sub
```

My objetive is create a TEXT FILE with these info:

```
SG5U0SX1914550051
CCHIME
ICHIME
BNONE
NQC703A014
PWIPCLEAN
n
r
O1175726
LRoute 703A
[
]
TP
```

Only the first line must change:
"S"& (The value on the next row")

If you could help he, will be great!!!

Comment: It's not clear what the exact problem is.  Does your code work?  "But in the first cell of column B I have to change the cell value of each of the values ​​in column A" - might be useful to post some sample data to show "before" and "after" for this...

Answer (score 0):

I already create a solution

(I copied a solution for another question, and change the parts I need)

```
Sub CreateFilesdummy()
    Dim sExportFolder As String, sFN As String
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Dim rName As Range
    Dim oFS As Object, oTxt As Object

    sExportFolder = "C:\Users\Data_Files\"
    Set oSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INDEX") '<-- set sheet name here
    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

    For Each rName In oSh.Range("A1:A" & oSh.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
        If rName.Value <> "" Then
            sFN = rName.Value & ".tar"
            Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & sFN, 2, True)
            oTxt.WriteLine "S" & rName  '<-- S (Serial Number)
            oTxt.WriteLine Range("B1")  '<-- C (Customer)
            oTxt.WriteLine Range("B2")  '<-- I (Division)
            oTxt.WriteLine Range("B3")  '<-- B (Board Style)
            oTxt.WriteLine Range("B4")  '<-- N (Tester Name/Equipment)
            oTxt.WriteLine Range("B5")  '<-- P (MES Test Process/Route Step)
            oTxt.WriteLine Range("B6")  '<-- n (Assembly Number) 
            oTxt.WriteLine Range("B7")  '<-- r (Assembly Revision)
            oTxt.WriteLine Range("B8")  '<-- O (MES Operator Id/Employee Number)
            oTxt.WriteLine Range("B9")  '<-- O (MES Operator Id/Employee Number)
            oTxt.WriteLine Range("B10") '<-- (Start Date Time)
            oTxt.WriteLine Range("B11") '<-- (end Date Time)
            oTxt.WriteLine Range("B12") '<-- T (Test Status)
            oTxt.Close
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

So, here is my another question,  I put create line by line, but there is a way, to put a determinated rage? How would you do it?

But thanks you all for this page and the info!!

Comment: It's best you didn't ask questions in the 'answer' field. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking `Ask Question`. You can also add a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation.